# Angular DatePicker to C# Datetime

Tags: c#, angular, datetime, datepicker, angular-material

I'm having trouble sending a request with two dates selected in angular-material date pickers to the server. The network seems to be sending them right however when it gets to the controller their value is DateTime default's value.

Requests Tried:

```
return this.http.post(endpoint, {
        StartDate,
        EndDate
    },
      {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text'
      });
```

```
return this.http.post(endpoint, {
        start: StartDate,
        end: EndDate
    },
      {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text'
      });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("File/Modifications")]
public IActionResult GetFileModificationReport([FromBody] DateTime start, [FromBody] DateTime end){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please wrap the start and end dates in your controller in one class...so you will be able to catch the data from the request body...

```
public class DateRange
{
   public DateTime start { get; set;}

   public DateTime end { get; set;}

}
```

.....

```
[HttpPost("File/Modifications")]
public IActionResult GetFileModificationReport(DateRange data){}
```

Comment: I added the [FromModel] to your suggestion and it worked! Thank you